# How to implement a LIMITLESS String and StringBuilder

Tags: java

Java's String and [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) are limited to a length of Integer.MAX_VALUE. In most use cases this is more than adequate, but I have just encountered a use case in which I need to handle and return a String greater than 2,684,354,560 characters.

This is required for capturing an incoming stream of characters, in which I do not have control over the size of the stream, nor do I have the option of re-architecting the solution. What I can do at most is replace a method in an existing module, or introduce a new class that replaces String and StringBuilder in that method.

As a temporary workaround, to prevent the OutOfMemory exception thrown when the StringBuilder length exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE, I implemented the follow safeAppend():

```java
    private void safeAppend(StringBuilder ret, String current) {
        if ((long)ret.length() + current.length() > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            String truncateLeadingPart;
            if (current.length() < ret.length()) {
                truncateLeadingPart = ret.substring(current.length());
            }
            else {
                int startIndex = (int)((long)ret.length()+current.length()-Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                truncateLeadingPart = ret.substring(Math.min(ret.length(), startIndex));
            }
            ret.setLength(0);
            ret.append(truncateLeadingPart);
        }
        ret.append(current);
    }
```

This methods truncates the leading part and always keeps the trailing 2,147,483,647 characters part. However, this workaround/safeguard proved to be inadequate for the task at hand because we cannot afford losing any data captured from the stream.

What is a recommended approach to implementing a `String` and `StringBuilder` that are **NOT limited** by an int max size?

A limit of a long max size could be sufficient. Also, a single `LimitlessString` class that can be appended efficiently like `StringBuilder` is also adequate.

Comment: Do you really have to hand over the data in one piece (as opposed to streaming it in chunks)? And does it really have to be in memory (as opposed to writing it to a temporary file on disk and returning a `File` -- or a `URL` to some kind of object storage system)? If you are handling huge pieces of data, you really cannot avoid adjusting your architecture to be able to deal with that.

Comment: @Thilo You are right in your observation. This needs to fit into an existing (very old) code. Handing over the data in multiple pieces requires a redesign of the entire module.

Comment: Your problem is array indexation. A string is under the hood basically a char array/sequence, which is limited by max length of arrays and such. Why can't you write the file to disc, and then just read relevant portions from disk? Will impact processing speed a bit, but you could always make a ram disk if speed is of the issue. That way you only have to update the file pointer from where to read.

Comment: Changing from `String` to `File` is probably the least intrusive change. Make sure you delete those huge files when done with them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wont be able to `String` or `StringBuffer` as the 32-bit length is baked into the interface. That's also true of arrays and NIO buffers, unfortunately (there have been proposals to fix this, but nothing at the time of writing).

Obviously streaming or using random file access would be a good solution if that is possible.

You are left with implementing something else. [Ropes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)) use a binary tree to represent composition of string parts. More common is to use an array of arrays, or for better GC an array of directly allocated (or memory-mapped file) NIO buffers. Someone remarked a few years ago that this area of Computer Science still has scope for more PhDs.

Comment: All answers here are helpful but I am accepting yours because I will most likely use the random file access solution you proposed here.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you ***Really-Really*** need to extend String/StringBuilder classes in such way you have to either create new class, that won't extend String/StringBuilder, because thay are marked as `final`, or you can change JRE binaries to make String/StringBuilder non-final. Anyway, both solutions sucks and will lead to huge support effort and will generate a lot of WTFs in future.

Comment: The problem is still that a string is using a `char[]` for data container https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#l111 which is in length limited by PHP_INT_MAX as the max array length. Op is better off using a streamreader imho for stability.

Comment: @Tschallacka And the `String` API.

Comment: @Tschallacka `PHP_INT_MAX`?

Comment: I guess in `MyOwnString` possible to implement any algorithm to avoid `Integer.MAX_VALUE` limitation (e.g. use `char[Integer.MAX_VALUE][Integer.MAX_VALUE]` and store indexes as `long` type, use `LinkedList<char[]>` or whatever you want)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yea, sorry, at work working with php, getting mixed up when writing, the java equivalent really for 32 bit numbers :-) Integer.MAX_VALUE

Answer (score 2):

String and StringBuilder are *final* classes and cannot be patched. `StringWriter` would have been better.

Nice would have been:

- not using two-byte chars, but bytes (CharBuffer upon ByteBuffer);
- compressing (GzipOutputStream);
- (as you did) periodically remove a huge chunk to a file or such;
- [An aside] in the newer java there is support for single byte encodings which would not allow more characters but would use half the memory.

You'll meet resizing on appending, so the system will slow down.